# linking content in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7, commerce

I want to create a linked image to a page of products. I know this is silly. I could do this in html very easily. I can't figure out the best way to do this. my constraints are.
1. Needs to be easy for owner to change images and pages they are linked to.
2. possible be able to add text.

I want the links to look something like the three blocks under the main image. http://www.livingproof.com/

Should I create a specific content type or a module for this? I'm fairly new to drupal but I'm finding my way around. I'm using drupal commerce for the store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is to make it a content type with whatever fields you need and display it with a view. So you'd make a content type called, for example, `Image Link`, with the fields `url`, `image`, and the `body` would be the text.

Then in the view you would choose the `url` and `text` fields first, excluding them from display. You would then add the `image` field and rewrite it as a link, using the available tokens - which will be described to you on page below the rewrite options.

Comment: Thats kinda what I was thinking but I don't have a url field. Do i need to create one?

Comment: that is close but I need the content to be an image not text.

Comment: Not sure you read my post correctly. The IMAGE field should be used in the view. That displays it as an image. Then you do "output as a link" and use the tokens to populate the link tag. But I'm glad you found a solution in any case :)